# Как в Nest JS передать необязательный параметр с помощью @Query() в Get запросе?

Tags: nestjs

в Swagger хочу отправить строковую переменную product_plan, но при этом хочу иметь возможность оставлять данное поле пустым. Пробовала добавить вопросительный знак после product_plan, но это не помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как справиться с этой проблемой

[image: swagger]

```
@Get('getQuery')
async getQuery(@Query('product_plan') product_plan?: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопросительный знак нужен только тайпскрипту, а вот чтобы настроить документацию для `Query` параметра, необходимо использовать соответствующий декоратор: `@ApiQuery()`

```typescript
@ApiQuery({ name: 'product_plan', required: false })
@Get('getQuery')
async getQuery(@Query('product_plan') product_plan?: string): boolean {
    return true;
}
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters

Comment: Добрый вечер, большое спасибо. Вы мне очень помогли)